# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume: mount failed: exit status 32

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, amazon-efs

I have `1 master node` and `2 worker nodes` built using `Amazon Linux` in my dev kubernetes cluster.

I have correctly mounted `AWS EFS` at `/share` on `worker1` and `worker2`.

Now, I am trying to create `pvc, pv and deploy` using the below manifests:

**PersistentVolume YAML**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: c2labs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    path: /share
    server: fs-0djdd8320680f8f98.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

**PersistentVolumeClaim YAML**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: c2labs-files
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

**Deploy YAML**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: test
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
            name: logs-files
      volumes:
        - name: logs-files
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: c2labs-files
```

Now, I am getting an error - `MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "c2labs" : mount failed: exit status 32`

Need help to determine what is causing this error.